# CSS hover to show button on sibling div

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I need to be able to show the Delete button (in the div with id=fdib) when the filter text (in the div with id=filter-text which is hidden normally with visibility:hidden) is hovered over.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="filter-text">
                <angular-tag align="'left'" text="filterModel.text"></angular-tag>
            </div>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <div id="fdib" class="fdib">
                <input id="delete-input-btn" type="button" title="Delete"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Whats the CSS that would make this happen? I originally had the following CSS when I had it before and it worked but I had to use tables to make the site work, and .sidebar was on another div outside the table.

```
.sidebar:hover .filter-delete-btn {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that stepback that requires because is inside a `td` the best you can do is blind the `:hover` event to the `td` then can look like this:

```
td:hover + td div#fdib #delete-input-btn {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6st2g/6/**.

*PD: Also your title is wrong because they aren't siblings*

Answer (score 0):

```
#fdib:hover #delete-input-btn {
    visibility: visible;
}
```